# Go back to Previous Directory in Linux using a C program

Tags: c, posix

I am in the directory `/home/destination` I need to go back to the `/home` directory. Any ideas on how to implement this using a C-program?

Comment: Are you looking for a C program that you can invoke from the command line and that sets the current directory? Or you want to set the current directory within the C program?

Comment: i need a c program running in the command line and changing the current directoy

Comment: What's wrong with using the shell's built-in `cd` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A program can only change *its own environment*. Thus, the program can [`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html) but it will not change the current directory of the parent. That's why `cd` can't be implemented as an external command.

Comment: so there is no way to change the directory of the parent. we can only go forward and backward in the program's environment

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) function for this:

```
chdir(".."); /* change current working directory, go one level up */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to go level up 
`chdir("..");` will do the work. But if you'd like to have behaviour like `cd -` then you should use this code:

```
char *prev;
prev = getcwd(prev, 0); /*POSIX.1-2001: will malloc enough memory*/
/*fail if prev is NULL, do something*/
chdir(prev);
free(prev);
```