# How does it work in the shell?

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t “cd” work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)
>   [Go back to Previous Directory in Linux using a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089834/go-back-to-previous-directory-in-linux-using-a-c-program)

The `chdir` function changes the directory, but it does not change the original directory.

For example:

```
$ pwd
  ~/home/loganaayahee
 $ cc chdir
 $ ./a.out ~/Desktop
 The directory change sucess and the current dir is ~/Desktop
 $ pwd
 ~/home/loganaayahee
```

The shell does not change the directory. What is the reason?
  so I do change the original directory what i do?. what purpose usedto the chdir() function?

Comment: It changes it in the environment of the new process. No process can change the environment of its parent.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate, right?

Comment: @CarlNorum It most certainly is. I remember answering it at least 3 times.

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089834/go-back-to-previous-directory-in-linux-using-a-c-program